# Is it possible to show message in DjangoAdmin on open?

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to display a message right after I open model admin page, is there a way? I know how to show it after save, but didn't find a way to show it on open.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Django Messages Framework for that.

```
from django.contrib import messages

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def each_context(self, request):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
        return super().each_context(request)
```

Messages more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message

AdminSite more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects

Comment: I know about messages, but will it work right after I open admin model page? I wonder is there some `on_open` method like `save_model`

Comment: signal User Logged in. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in